# Better method for creating theme in Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

I'm often customizing theme in tumblr, but this editor is terrible. Is there some better possibility for creating theme in tumblr under Linux (Ubuntu) OS?
I'm thinking about using vim. But I have to copy the text into vim, edit something and paste it to tumblr web editor, which is uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look at [Tumblr Themr](http://tumblrthemr.icelab.com.au/). I haven't tried it myself though.

Answer (score 1):

I work with [TumblrThemr](http://tumblrthemr.icelab.com.au/) and [Tumblr HTML5 Blank Theme](https://github.com/wxrod/Tumblr-HTML5-Blank-Theme).